# Adding WinRM .adm template to Win Svr 2003 AD

Tags: group-policy, winrm

I'm trying to enable WinRM on our machines via Group Policy. When I use GPMC against one of our Win Svr 2003 DC's, add a new GPO and edit it, and navigate to Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates, there's no node but "All Settings", and that is empty. I then read somewhere that I'd need to add the `windowsremotemanagement.adm` and `windowsremoteshell.adm` policy templates to the DC. I did apply the KB968930 Update (Windows Management Framework Core package) on all our DCs, which I thought would provide those templates.

Could someone tell me how to enable these admin templates? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it... They were in `C:\Windows\inf` on the DC's. Added them into the Administrative Templates node via the "Add/Remove Templates..." context menu item, and I was good to go.